# Convert .jpeg image to .tiff 1 bit - (G4) by only javascript

Tags: image, compression, tiff

I need to convert image file from (ex: .jpg, png..) to (.tiff) 1 bit(G4) just by javascript.I tried searching for a library on google. But I couldn't find any one. Please help me!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is too braod to have a valuable feedback. Please see How to Ask and provide a minimal reproducible example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @RushilPachchigar Thanks for your reminder. Sorry for my poor English. I will revise my question. thank you!!